# Create laravel migration file from MySQL dump

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

There is a MySQL request to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_edited_message` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique identifier for this entry',
  `chat_id` bigint COMMENT 'Unique chat identifier',
  `message_id` bigint UNSIGNED COMMENT 'Unique message identifier',
  `user_id` bigint NULL COMMENT 'Unique user identifier',
  `edit_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date the message was edited in timestamp format',
  `text` TEXT COMMENT 'For text messages, the actual UTF-8 text of the message max message length 4096 char utf8',
  `entities` TEXT COMMENT 'For text messages, special entities like usernames, URLs, bot commands, etc. that appear in the text',
  `caption` TEXT COMMENT  'For message with caption, the actual UTF-8 text of the caption',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `chat_id` (`chat_id`),
  KEY `message_id` (`message_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),

  FOREIGN KEY (`chat_id`) REFERENCES `chat` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`chat_id`, `message_id`) REFERENCES `tb_message` (`chat_id`, `id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tb_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

I created a migration:

```
...
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_edited_message', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';

            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('chat_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('message_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->timestamp('edit_date')->nullable();
            $table->text('text')->nullable();
            $table->text('entities')->nullable();
            $table->text('caption')->nullable();
        });

        Schema::table('tb_edited_message', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('chat_id')->references('id')->on('tb_chat');
            $table->foreign('chat_id', 'message_id')->references('chat_id', 'id')->on('tb_message');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('tb_user');
        });
    }
...
```

But after start `php artisan migrate`:
[image]

Error in line: `$table->foreign('chat_id', 'message_id')->references('chat_id', 'id')->on('tb_message');`

---

Tables `tb_chat` AND `tb_user` AND `tb_message`
**This tables were created before** `tb_edited_message`

```
....
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';

            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->boolean('is_bot')->default(false);
            $table->char('first_name', 255)->default('');
            $table->char('last_name', 255)->nullable();
            $table->char('username', 255)->nullable();
            $table->char('language_code', 10)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('username');
        });
    }
....
```

---

```
....
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_chat', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';

            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('old_id')->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['private', 'group', 'supergroup', 'channel']);
            $table->char('title', 255)->nullable();
            $table->char('username', 255)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('all_members_are_administrators')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('old_id');
        });
    }
....
```

---

```
.....
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_message', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('chat_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->timestamp('date')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('forward_from')->nullable()->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('forward_from_chat')->nullable()->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('forward_from_message_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('forward_date')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('reply_to_chat')->nullable()->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('reply_to_message')->nullable()->index();
            $table->text('media_group_id')->nullable();

            $table->text('text')->nullable();
            $table->text('entities')->nullable();
            $table->text('audio')->nullable();
            $table->text('document')->nullable();
            $table->text('photo')->nullable();
            $table->text('sticker')->nullable();
            $table->text('video')->nullable();
            $table->text('voice')->nullable();
            $table->text('video_note')->nullable();
            $table->text('contact')->nullable();
            $table->text('location')->nullable();
            $table->text('venue')->nullable();
            $table->text('caption')->nullable();
            $table->text('new_chat_members')->nullable();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('left_chat_member')->nullable()->index();

            $table->char('new_chat_title', 255)->nullable();
            $table->text('new_chat_photo')->nullable();

            $table->boolean('delete_chat_photo')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('group_chat_created')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('supergroup_chat_created')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('channel_chat_created')->default(false);

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('migrate_to_chat_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('migrate_from_chat_id')->nullable()->index();

            $table->text('pinned_message')->nullable();

            $table->primary(['chat_id', 'id']);
        });

        Schema::table('tb_message', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('tb_user');
            $table->foreign('chat_id')->references('id')->on('tb_chat');
            $table->foreign('forward_from')->references('id')->on('tb_user');
            $table->foreign('forward_from_chat')->references('id')->on('tb_chat');
            $table->foreign('reply_to_chat', 'reply_to_message')->references('chat_id', 'id')->on('tb_message');
            $table->foreign('left_chat_member')->references('id')->on('tb_user');
        });
    }
.....
```

**This migrations for [TelegramBot](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core)** - which so far without the support of Laravel (no migrations)

Сreate migrations for these [tables](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/blob/master/structure.sql)

Comment: the tb_message doesnot exist thats why that error.
first u need to migrate that.

Comment: also note when you do mysql dump the table will be in alphabetical order so if ur referencing a table which is not in the database it will not be able to add the foreign key constraint..

Comment: Tables `tb_chat` AND `tb_user` AND `tb_message` were created before `tb_edited_message`

Comment: What is the primary key of `tb_message`?

Comment: @paul-spiegel `$table->primary(['chat_id', 'id']);`

Comment: @paul-spiegel MySQl damp https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/blob/master/structure.sql

Comment: From your link: `chat_id bigint COMMENT 'Unique chat identifier',` Why isn't it UNSIGNED?

Comment: @paul-spiegel in laravel Foreign keys with migrations must be UNSIGNED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L418

```
/**
 * Specify a foreign key for the table.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $columns
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
public function foreign($columns, $name = null)
{
    return $this->indexCommand('foreign', $columns, $name);
}
```

We can see that the first parameter is the column or an array of columns. The second parameter seams to be the (optional) constraint name. (Though your error message suggests that when two parameters are used, the first one is the constraint name and the second is the column name or an array of column names.)

So you should wrap the column names into an array:

```
$table->foreign(['chat_id', 'message_id'])->references(['chat_id', 'id'])->on('tb_message');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue due to the tables I was referencing not yet existing. What I did was I loaded all the tables first without foreign key constraints in one migration. Then in a second migration I added all the foreign key constraints to each table.

Comment: Tables tb_chat AND tb_user AND tb_message were created before tb_edited_message. They are created

Comment: Were they migrated though after being created? It looks like one table migrated successfully before your error in the screenshot. If you’re migrating them together that might be why. You could test it by commenting out the foreign key and then doing a second migration with just the foreign key. You can always roll it back and do it the way you’d like to later once you identify the problem.